# How to update a progress bar in a loop inside a loop inside an ajax async call inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an application using kendoGrid where i update selected rows after saving them to our db.

Sometimes we have 1000+ rows so i have to partition the rows in order not to bog down the application. This takes quite a long time so i wanted to display a progress bar to help users see the progress on the updates.

The problem is that the progress bar doesn't update in each iteration. As i step through using chrome debugger i can see the progress bar update. but when i run the script in real time nothing happens.

**HTML**

```
<div id="progressbar-wrapper">
    <div id="progressbar-outer" style="display: table;margin: 0 auto;background-color: #FFFFFF;border: 5px solid #000000;width: 50%;height: 30px;opacity: 1;z-index: 9998">
        <div id="progressbar" style="float:left;width: 0;height: 30px;background-color:#000000;border: 0;opacity: 1;z-index: 99999">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="loading-animation" style="position: fixed;top: 150px;left: 0;height: 120px;width: 100%;font-size: 100px;line-height: 120px;text-align: center;color: #000000;z-index: 9999;">
        ...SAVING...<br /><small>Saving Lines</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var progressbar = {};
$(function () {

    progressbar = {

        /** initial progress */
        progress: 0,

        /** maximum width of progressbar */
        progress_max: 0,

        /** The inner element of the progressbar (filled box). */
        $progress_bar: $('#progressbar'),

        /** Method to set the progressbar.
         */
        set: function (num) {
            if (this.progress_max && num) {
                this.progress = num / this.progress_max * 100;
                console.log('percent: ' + this.progress + '% - ' + num + '/' + this.progress_max);
                this.$progress_bar.width(String(this.progress) + '%');
            }
        },

        fn_wrap: function (num) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                this.set(num);
            }, 0);
        }

    };

});



var processedPartitions = 0;
var partitions = saveData.partition(30); //saveData is the selected saved rows

//Iterate through partitions
for (var i = 0; i < partitions.length; i++) {

    var urlForWindow = "/Data/Save/";
    $.ajax({
        url: urlForWindow,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(partitions[i]),
        async: true,
        complete: function () {
            processedPartitions++;
            if (processedPartitions === partitions.length) {

                //PROGRESS BAR (DOESNT WORK, Doesnt show or update the progressbar in real time) ==========================================

                //Get the full number of rows getting updated.
                var iterations = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < partitions.length; i++) {
                    iterations = iterations + partitions[i].length;
                }

                //add total number of records to update as the iterations
                progressbar.progress_max = iterations;

                //make the progress bar visable before updating //does not show
                $("#progressbar-wrapper").css("display", "block");

                //start counter of rows updated
                var recordsUpdated = 0;

                //begin update loop
                var mainGrid = $("#mainGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                $.each(mainGrid.dataSource.data(), function () {

                    if (this.RowSelected === true) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < partitions.length; i++) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < partitions[i].length; j++) {

                                    var row = mainGrid.dataSource.getByUid(this.uid);
                                    row.set("RowSelected", "false");
                                    row.set("dirty", "false");

                                    //after update iterate recordsupdated
                                    recordsUpdated++;

                                //update the progress bar if not complete //doesnt update in realtime
                                if (iterations >= recordsUpdated) {
                                    progressbar.set(recordsUpdated);        
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                //turn off progressbar after complete // never shows in realtime, never shown closing 
                $("#progressbar-wrapper").css("display", "none");

                //Success message
                alert("Saved");
            }

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.resonseText);
        }
    });
}
```

So stepping through the code line by line, I can see that everything works. But when running in real-time. The progress bar never shows. Its like the entire page freezes.

Comment: Do NOT use interval or timeout to loop Ajax. Call the function that runs the next ajax from the success or done of the ajax call. You can use setTimeout from in there too but do not wrap ajax in loops

Comment: Browsers are single threaded. The bar won't be updated until the js halts...

Comment: What Jonas said. Something really worth understanding is the Event Loop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Two for loops with `for (var i = 0; i < partitions.length; i++) {` ??

Comment: so the ajax call in the loop is to loop through the partitions as of not to send all the data to the api all at once. It has to send 1 partition at a time. Also you can see I'm NOT using interval or timeout on that ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out. Just had to separate the two processes. The ajax completes and sends the complete flag to a following method to update the grid using event loops.

```
//Get the number of saved data rows. That = total iteration
var iterations = saveData.length; //get data

var processedPartitions = 0;
var partitions = saveData.partition(30); partition data

//write buyer to Database First (Quickest method)
for (var p = 0; p < partitions.length; p++) {
    var urlForWindow = "/Data/Save/";
    $.ajax({
        url: urlForWindow,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(partitions[p]),
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (result) {
            successComplete = 1; //1 means success
        },
        complete: function () {
            processedPartitions++;
            //check if all partitions processed
            if (processedPartitions === partitions.length) {
                successComplete = successComplete + 1; //2 means successful completion
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.resonseText); //0 means error
        }
    });
}


//PROGRESS BAR ================================================
//max progress bar
progressbar.progress_max = iterations;

var mainGrid = $("#mainGrid").data("kendoGrid");

var i = 0; //partition #
var j = 0; //line #
var linesUpdated = 0; //update complete #


//make the progress bar visable before updating
$("#progressbar-wrapper").css("display", "block");


//then loop through update grid methods
(function innerloop() {

    try {
        //If end 
        var testPart = (partitions[i].length - 1); //30 but starts at 0
    } catch (err) {
        //exit loop
        return;
    }

    //Get the length of the partition
    var thisPartitionLength = (partitions[i].length - 1); //30 but starts at 0


    if (thisPartitionLength >= j && successComplete === 2) {

        $.each(mainGrid.dataSource.data(),
            function () {

                if (this.RowSelected === true) { 

                    //get id
                    var row = mainGrid.dataSource.getByUid(this.uid);

                    //unselect and turn off dirty
                    row.set("RowSelected", "false");
                    row.set("dirty", "false");
                    linesUpdated++;
                }
            });
        //update line #
        j++;
        //update progressbar
        progressbar.set(linesUpdated);
    }

    if (j <= thisPartitionLength) {
        //loop if not complete with partition
        setTimeout(innerloop, 0);
    } else {
        if (j > thisPartitionLength) {
            //if end of partition reset the line # and increase partition # and continue loop
            i++;
            j = 0;
            setTimeout(innerloop, 0);
        }

        //on complete
        if (linesUpdated === iterations) {

            //Success message
            alert("Saved");
        }
    }
})();
```

**UPDATE**

Ugh!! this doesn't work in IE11!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform multiple tasks at the same time as javascript is single threaded. However HTML5 introduced web workers and i believe you can achieve your requirements with web worker so that background thread will be used for server interaction an the main thread will be spare for UI updates.

[Web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)